# Dbpedia: How to retrieve all distinct car models and its manufacturers?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

To be used on an flyweight pattern in my PHP classes, I've tried to use sparql on dbpedia endpoint to retrieve a list of all car models and its respectives manufacturers:

```
SELECT distinct ?model, ?manufacturer_name WHERE {
  ?x dbpedia2:manufacturer ?z .
  ?x foaf:name ?model .
  ?manufacturer ?y2 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Automotive_industry> .
  ?manufacturer foaf:name ?manufacturer_name
}
```

Unfortunately, the result was not the expect, because rows like "Fiat 147 | Fiat" have not returned.

How can I fix this sparql code?

Comment: your query is just wrong and returns the cartesian product which is larger than the 10000 rows you'll by a single request. I mean, it's quite obvious isn't it? variable `?z` is wrong, it should be `?x dbpedia2:manufacturer ?manufacturer.` otherwise the triple patterns won't be connected

Comment: you also have to take into account Wikipedia redirects, that's why "Fiat 147" doesn't show up. It's manufacturer is `dbr:Fiat` which itself is redirected to `dbr:Fiat_Automobiles`

Comment: `SELECT distinct ?model ?manufacturer_name WHERE {
  ?x dbo:manufacturer/dbo:wikiPageRedirects? ?manufacturer .
  ?x foaf:name ?model .
  ?manufacturer dbo:industry <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Automotive_industry> .
  ?manufacturer foaf:name ?manufacturer_name
} order by ?manufacturer_name ?model`